# Wrapping customer address primitive into a class

Tags: php, oop

I'm passing in a customer's address as an object to a class using object injection instead of passing an array. My question is on the customer's address object what would be the best method for setting up the setters and getters?

I did think about using something like this:

```
public function __call() {
 // search for set or get and act accordingly or throw an exception.
}
```

but, i thought that it might be too vague. Should I just make the getters myself?

```
public function setFirstName();
public function setLastName();
public function setCompany();
public function setAddressLine1();
public function setCity();
public function setZipCode();
public function setPhone();
public function setCountry();

// then do the same for the get methods.
```

Or maybe I could combine some methods with __call (magic methods) and some declared methods?

Please can you let me know what might be the best method or alternative way of doing this and why.

Thank you in advance for your time,

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I felt the same but it just felt strange writing so many methods just to hold a trxtual string.

Comment: Thank you, Arkascha. If you put that as an answer I will mark it as complete :)

Comment: As you suggest :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb: prefer explicit over implicit. So explicit setters and getters usually are the preferred style.

Look at it this way: getters and setters only hand over a payload in their primitive form, though they may do much more if required: filtering, validating, fixing, enhancing, ... But above all: their existence is a clear sign the class expects and grants a user to get or set a value. Whereas with these "magical getters and setters" instead you fly in the blind. Same for IDEs: now way their auto completion can work with them. So keep it in style and explicit. Others will thank you for it :-)